# add values to an array within a state object using useState React hook

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have a state object called 'team' and the object structure looks like this.

```
team = {
    name: 'TeamA',
    players: [
        player1,
        player2
    ]
}
```

How can I add more players (player3, player4) to the 'team' object using useState hook in ReactJS?

Each player is also an object.

Expected result:

```
team = {
    name: 'TeamA',
    players: [
        player1,
        player2,
        player3,
        player4
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your next state depends on the previous state, you should use a callback inside useState.

```
useState(prevState => {
    return {...prevState, players: [...prevState.players, player3, player4] }
})
```